Python Gaze tracking mediapipe doesn't show anything result
Hi I wan't to use eye gaze tracking in python code.
So I found some github repository for my purpose.
enter link description here
I ran the code in google colab, but it does not appear anything without any errors.
There are no issue about this in that github repository.
Also I found several gaze tracking code but it does not appear anything either like this. So I thought this is the problem of gaze tracking mediapipe model.
How can I solve this problem?


You need to enable the refine_landmarks=True setting for face mesh to return the full landmarks including the irises
you should change main.py line 181 to
with map_face_mesh.FaceMesh(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5, refine_landmarks=True) as face_mesh:

